# CUDA and C++ simple project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, cuda

I am trying to create a CUDA + C++ project. Basically a .cpp project that calls for some CUDA kernel. So I simply followed the example here, which basically adds two vectors. The kernel does the summation job:
http://blog.norture.com/2012/10/gpu-parallel-programming-in-vs2012-with-nvidia-cuda/

Here is the code,

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "cuda.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

using namespace std;

__global__ void saxpy(int n, float a, float *x, float *y)
{
  int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  if (i < n) y[i] = a*x[i] + y[i];
}

int main(void)
{
  int N = 1<<20;
  float *x, *y, *d_x, *d_y;
  x = (float*)malloc(N*sizeof(float));
  y = (float*)malloc(N*sizeof(float));

  cudaMalloc(&d_x, N*sizeof(float));
  cudaMalloc(&d_y, N*sizeof(float));

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    x[i] = 1.0f;
    y[i] = 2.0f;
  }

  cudaMemcpy(d_x, x, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(d_y, y, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  // Perform SAXPY on 1M elements
  saxpy<<<(N+255)/256, 256>>>(N, 2.0, d_x, d_y);

  cudaMemcpy(y, d_y, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  float maxError = 0.0f;
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    maxError = max(maxError, abs(y[i]-4.0f));
  cout << "Max error: " << maxError;
}
```

When I built I got this error:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: CUDATest001, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>  CUDATestZeroZeroOne.cpp
1>CUDATestZeroZeroOne.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol threadIdx
1>CUDATestZeroZeroOne.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol blockIdx
1>CUDATestZeroZeroOne.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol blockDim
1>D:\Projects\CUDATest001\x64\Debug\CUDATest001.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

If the line `saxpy<<<(N+255)/256, 256>>>(N, 2.0, d_x, d_y);` is commented out, then this error appeared:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: CUDATest001, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>  CUDATestZeroZeroOne.cpp
1>CUDATestZeroZeroOne.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol threadIdx
1>CUDATestZeroZeroOne.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol blockIdx
1>CUDATestZeroZeroOne.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol blockDim
1>D:\Projects\CUDATest001\x64\Debug\CUDATest001.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

**I am using vs2012 + CUDA 5.5. I started with a empty C++ win32 console project, added a .cpp file which includes all the code above.** I am not even sure at this point should it be a .cu or a .cpp file?

Anyone has any idea how to make this work? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried changing the type of file to `.cu`?

Comment: @sgar91: Yea it does not change anything. Even though I changed the extension to cu it still shows cpp file in the solution window. And the compile gives same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the context menu for your project, click `Build Customizations`. Turn on the `CUDA 5.5` target.

In the context menu for your `.cpp` file, click `Rename` and rename it to `.cu`.

In the context menu for your `.cu` file (that you just renamed), select `Properties`. Then go to `General` and make sure `Item Type` is set to `CUDA C/C++`.

Rebuild.

When you start a new CUDA project, you can select `Templates > NVIDIA > CUDA 5.5 > CUDA 5.5 Runtime` to get a project that should compile without any modifications.

Comment: Yea, the third advice makes a difference. So many threads, but none of them mentioned using Item Type CUDA C/C++. Thanks a lot!!